# How to remove local notification from notification center?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to remove all local notification from notification center?
I tried to cancellAllLocalNotification, But it cancel whole notification which wasn't 
notified yet (still in schedule).
But I want to just clear notification center, and I don't want to unschedule rest notification.

I think I must save whole notification and, clear all notification with cancelAllLocalNotification, and re-schedule rest notification.
But I feel it ugly solution.. ;-(

Comment: check it i hope it will help http://josh-asch.net/2012/02/29/ios-development-remove-old-notifications-from-notification-center/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is create the notification with userInfo object atacched (a Dictionary). Each time you create a notification create also a UUID (a unique identifier) add it to a dictionary and attach that dictionary to the notification. When you need to delete use the UUID string as a unique value to specific delete a particular notification.